# Laravel 5, My create method is very slow, how can improve it?

Tags: php, laravel-5, upload, gallery, image-uploading

For my website I want to create a gallery and upload photos. These photo must resize to two formats.

I build a method in my controller to create galleries, but is very slow and required too much memory. How can I improve it?

Is it possible to do it like this or need i do an ajax call?

```
public function store(GalleryCreateRequest $request)
{
   //dd($request->all());

    $input = $request->all();
    $name = str_replace(' ', '_', $input['name']);
    if (Input::file('featured_image')) {
        $featured = Input::file('featured_image');
        $extensieFeatured = $featured->getClientOriginalExtension();
        if (!file_exists('images/'.$name)) {
            mkdir('images/'.$name, 0777, true);
        }
        $path = 'images/'.$name;
        $featuredName = str_replace(' ', '_', $input['name']) . '_featured' . '.' . $extensieFeatured;
        $featured->move($path, $featuredName);
        $input['featured_image'] = $featuredName;
        //landcape or Portrait
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path.'/'.$featuredName);
        if ($width > $height) {
            //landscape
            Image::make($path.'/'.$featuredName)->resize(1500, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($path.'/web_'.$featuredName);
            Image::make($path.'/'.$featuredName)->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($path.'/thumbs_'.$featuredName);
        } else {
            //portrait
            Image::make($path.'/'.$featuredName)->resize(null, 1500, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($path.'/web_'.$featuredName);
            Image::make($path.'/'.$featuredName)->resize(null, 300, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($path.'/thumbs_'.$featuredName);
        }
    }
    $gallery = Galleries::create($input);
    $gallery->categories()->attach($request->input('categories_list'));


    $files = Input::file('images');
    $uploadcount = 1;
    if (!file_exists('images/'.$name.'/')) {
        mkdir('images/'.$name.'/', 0777, true);
    }
    $destinationPath = 'images/'.$name.'/';
    if (!file_exists($destinationPath.'/')) {
        mkdir($destinationPath.'/', 0777, true);
    }
    if (!file_exists($destinationPath.'/')) {
        mkdir($destinationPath.'/', 0777, true);
    }
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $extensie = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $input['name']) . $uploadcount . '.' . $extensie;
        $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        Photos::create(['file' => $filename, 'galleries_id' => $gallery->id]);
        //landcape or Portrait
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path.'/'.$featuredName);
        if ($width > $height) {
            //landscape
            Image::make($destinationPath.'/'.$filename)->resize(1500, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($destinationPath.'/web_'.$filename);
            Image::make($destinationPath.'/'.$filename)->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($destinationPath.'/thumbs_'.$filename);
        } else {
            //portrait
            Image::make($destinationPath.'/'.$filename)->resize(null, 1500, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($destinationPath.'/web_'.$filename);
            Image::make($destinationPath.'/'.$filename)->resize(null, 300, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($destinationPath.'/thumbs_'.$filename);
        }
        $uploadcount++;
    }

    Session::flash('created_galleries', 'The Gallery has been created with ' . $uploadcount . ' images');
    return redirect('/admin/galleries');
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to improve the performance?

Comment: can you add some metrics ? how many photos at a time ? too slow or too much memory are too subjective and not very factual.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looping through many large images and also processing them it will probably be a long and memory intensive process no matter what. It does make sense to use an AJAX request for this. You might also be interested in using laravel's [queue system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues) as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things which you need to consider for performance,

**Asynchronous Jobs:**

For time consuming jobs like uploading a big file to cloud storage or sending email, we use [Asynchronous jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#dispatching-jobs).

**Limit Upload Size:**

In simple scenario your code should work fine, but the problem is when a user is uploading large file. Well obviously it should be handled first at server level and than your code level.

**Suggestions:**

```
    public function submit(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $name = str_replace(' ', '_', $input['name']);
        //if (Input::file('featured_image')) {
        // When you already has access to request why requesting again using a proxy call throught Input Facade

        if ($request->hasFile('featured_image')) {

            $featured = $request->file('featured_image');

            $extensieFeatured = $featured->getClientOriginalExtension();

            // Since you're not using else 
            // Mean directory is either there already or you're creating it.
            // in both cases $request->file()->move() should help
            /*if (!file_exists('images/' . $name)) {
                mkdir('images/' . $name, 0777, true);
            }*/

            $path = 'images/' . $name;

            $featuredName = str_replace(' ', '_', $input['name']) . '_featured' . '.' . $extensieFeatured;

            $featured->move($path, $featuredName);

            $input['featured_image'] = $featuredName;
            //landcape or Portrait

            // reading a file at disk is 0.2 ms to 10 ms when you already have a file in memory why reading it again.
            //list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path . '/' . $featuredName);

            $image = Image::make($featured);

            if ($featured->width > $featured->height) {
                //landscape

                $image->resize(1500, null, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save($path . '/web_' . $featuredName);

                $image->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save($path . '/thumbs_' . $featuredName);

            } else {
                //portrait
                $image->resize(null, 1500, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save($path . '/web_' . $featuredName);

                $image->resize(null, 300, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save($path . '/thumbs_' . $featuredName);
            }
        }

        $gallery = Galleries::create($input);
        $gallery->categories()->attach($request->input('categories_list'));


        $files = $request->file('images');
        $uploadcount = 1;

        // You don't need to check this.
        // since you're creating directories, mean www-data has the access to the file system
        // so laravel UploadedFile can handle this.
        /*if (!file_exists('images/' . $name . '/')) {
            mkdir('images/' . $name . '/', 0777, true);
        }*/

        $destinationPath = 'images/' . $name . '/';
        // You don't need this.
        /*if (!file_exists($destinationPath . '/')) {
            mkdir($destinationPath . '/', 0777, true);
        }*/

        // not even this.
        /*if (!file_exists($destinationPath . '/')) {
            mkdir($destinationPath . '/', 0777, true);
        }*/
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $extensie = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $input['name']) . $uploadcount . '.' . $extensie;

            $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

            Photos::create(['file' => $filename, 'galleries_id' => $gallery->id]);

            // You can repeat the above procedure again here.
            //landcape or Portrait
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path . '/' . $featuredName);

            if ($width > $height) {
                //landscape
                Image::make($destinationPath . '/' . $filename)->resize(1500, null, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save($destinationPath . '/web_' . $filename);
                Image::make($destinationPath . '/' . $filename)->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save($destinationPath . '/thumbs_' . $filename);
            } else {
                //portrait
                Image::make($destinationPath . '/' . $filename)->resize(null, 1500, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save($destinationPath . '/web_' . $filename);
                Image::make($destinationPath . '/' . $filename)->resize(null, 300, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save($destinationPath . '/thumbs_' . $filename);
            }
            $uploadcount++;
        }

        Session::flash('created_galleries', 'The Gallery has been created with ' . $uploadcount . ' images');
        return redirect('/admin/galleries');
    }
```

**Word Of Advice:**

Don't write thick (too much code inside a function) controllers, try to use SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) and SOLID Principles. Look into [Lucid](https://github.com/lucid-architecture/laravel)